# How do I use a Radiobutton to input a set integer to a variable?

Tags: python, string, input, radio-button, tkinter

**I have used the line of code below to input a variable for "BAI_var1" in a multiple choice command line software.**

```
BAI_var1 = input ("Please enter 0 for not at all, 1 for somewhat, 2 for moderatly or 3 for a lot:")
```

**Here is my Graphic User Interface:**

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

    class App:
        def __init__(self, master):
            w = Label(master, text="1. Anxiety, nervousness, worry or fear")
            w.pack()

            v = IntVar()
            Radiobutton(master, text="0 for not at all", variable=v, value=1).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            Radiobutton(master, text="1 for somewhat", variable=v, value=2).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            Radiobutton(master, text="2 for moderatly", variable=v, value=3).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
            Radiobutton(master, text="3 for a lot", variable=v, value=4).pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")

            self.button = Button(master, text="BACK", fg="red", command=self.button6)
            self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
            self.button = Button(master, text="NEXT", fg="red", command=self.button5)
            self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)


        def button6(self):
            print "Sam is awesome!GAJONGA" 

        def button5(self):
            print "PYTHON FOR THE WIN! GIAN SAYS PYTHON = FILTHY" 

    master = Tk()
    app = App(master)
    master.mainloop()
```

**My problem is that I don't know how to use a *Radiobutton* to input a set integer to a variable.**

Comment: But the answers are all integers and you seem to be getting the integers fine, at least if the code you posted runs. Can you show an example where you actually need to get a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map the integer values to the strings they represent:

```
choices = {
    1: "not at all",
    2: "somewhat",
    3: "moderately",
    4: "a lot"
}
```

You can then use this to create the UI:

```
for (i in sorted(choices.keys())):
    label = "%s - %s" % (i, choices[i])
    rb=Radiobutton(master, text=label, variable=v, value=i)
    rb.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
```

When you need to fetch the values, obviously it's just a simple dictionary lookup using the value of the variable as the key.

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan! I am still struggling because I do not know how to use the code you just shared with me :-( Would you please tell me more and/or point me in the direction to some documentation? I will  try to google "dictionary maps".

Comment: I took a wild guess and pasted the code you shared with me in my code. Unsurprisingly it did not work...

Comment: I searched Python Dictionarys and found a great video on youtube :-) I now understand how to work with Dictionarys :-D